# Performing a condition based on the current URL with react.js and react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using React.js & react router v6

Is there a way I can extract information from the current URL? Let's say my current URL is this: `localhost:3000/about/x567gfh67ssd90g`

I simply want to perform a condition based on the current URL. Is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you read the React Router docs which explain how to use things like path parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  });
  return ();
};
```

You can get pathname using useLocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add connected-react-router to your project. This way you will have access to all the current route information in your redux-store. This will also allow you to "Time travel" through your SPA. When you hit the backbutton instead of going to the previous page you can go back through state.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider, ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import { store, history } from './Store/store';
import { App } from './App/App';

render(
    <Provider store={ store } context={ ReactReduxContext } >
        <ConnectedRouter context={ ReactReduxContext } history={ history }>
                <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

If you install the redux-devTools in your browser you can look at all the URL data like this- Obviously this is a little more advanced but you it will give you access to everything you need.

[image]